# Problem omitting optional word in python3 regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need a regex that captures 2 groups: a movie and the year. Optionally, there could be a 'from ' string between them.

My expected results are:

```
first_query="matrix 2013" => ('matrix', '2013')
second_query="matrix from 2013" => ('matrix', '2013')
third_query="matrix" => ('matrix', None)
```

I've done 2 simulations on https://regex101.com/ for python3:
I- `r"(.+)(?:from ){0,1}([1-2]\d{3})"`
Doesn't match first_query and third_query, also doesn't omit 'from' in group one, which is what I want to avoid.

II- `r"(.+)(?:from ){1}([1-2]\d{3})"`
Works with second_query, but does not match first_query and third_query.

Is it possible to match all three strings, omitting the 'from ' string from the first group?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(.+?)(?:\s+(?:from\s+)?([12]\d{3}))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccsVcw/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(.+?)` - Group 1: any 1+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\s+(?:from\s+)?([12]\d{3}))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?:from\s+)?` - an optional sequence of `from` substring followed with 1+ whitespaces
  - `([12]\d{3})`  - Group 2: `1` or `2` followed with 3 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

This will output your patters, but have a space too much in from of the number:

```
import re

pat = r"^(.+?)(?: from)? ?(\d+)?$"


text = """matrix 2013
matrix from 2013
matrix"""

for t in text.split("\n"):
    print(re.findall(pat,t))
```

Output:

```
[('matrix', '2013')]
[('matrix', '2013')]
[('matrix', '')]
```

Explanation:

```
 ^           start of string
(.+?)        lazy anythings as few as possible
(?: from)?   non-grouped optional ` from`
 ?           optional space
(\d+=)?$     optional digits till end of string
```

---

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VD0SZb/1

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile( r"""
    ^\s*              # start of string (optional whitespace)
    (?P<title>\S+)    # one or more non-whitespace characters (title)
    (?:\s+from)?      # optionally, some space followed by the word 'from'
    \s*               # optional whitespace
    (?P<year>[0-9]+)? # optional digit string (year)
    \s*$              # end of string (optional whitespace)
""", re.VERBOSE )

for query in [ 'matrix 2013', 'matrix from 2013', 'matrix' ]:
    m = re.match( pattern, query )
    if m: print( m.groupdict() )

# Prints:
# {'title': 'matrix', 'year': '2013'}
# {'title': 'matrix', 'year': '2013'}
# {'title': 'matrix', 'year': None}
```

Disclaimer: this regex does not contain the logic necessary to reject the first two matches on the grounds that The Matrix actually came out in 1999.

Comment: Also a nice solution! It is a good way to document regex code by breaking it in lines.